# Double integral notation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, notation

Over a region D (a bounded, closed and connected region), can we write the double integral $\iint\limits_D \, f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ as $\iint\limits_D \, f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$ (note the order of $dx$ and $dy$)?

Comment: The order you take the integral in doesn't matter, all it affects is the constants of integration.  Personally I don't like the notation $\iint dxdy$ because it's ambiguous, I much prefer the notation $\iint dxdy = \int dy\int dx$--no ambiguity here.  And yes it's true that $\int dx\int dy = \int dy \int dx$ (again, only the constants of integration will change depending on the region--they won't if it's a rectangular region).

Comment: If you want to show that you are integrating over a region, then you should write: $\iint_D dA$ or $\iiint_D dV$, etc.  Then when you're ready to actually take the integral, switch to single integrals (as per my previous comment).

Answer (score 3):

If either:

- $f\ge 0$;
- $\iint\limits_D |f(x,y)| dxdy<\infty$;
- $\iint\limits_D |f(x,y)| dydx<\infty$,

you can. This is true if, for example, $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion
$$ \iint_D f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$
for $D\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is *bad* notation. It suggests that what you are looking at is an iterated integral, where you integrate with respect to $x$ first and afterwards with respect to $y$. But it is *not*, it's an integral over a region in $\mathbb R^2$. You are integrating with respect to the two-dimensional Lebesgue-measure. Better notations are 
$$
\iint_D f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA\ , \int_D f(x,y)\,\mathrm dA\ , \int_D f\,\mathrm d\lambda
$$
or variants of that. Those notations don't suggest an iterated integral.

---

If we really wanted to interpret $\iint_D f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ as an iterated integral, it would be
$$
\int_{\operatorname{pr}_2(D)} \left( \int_{\{x \in\mathbb R \mid (x,y)\in D\}} f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx \right) \mathrm dy
$$
where $\operatorname{pr}_2$ is the projection $(x,y)\mapsto y$ and $\{\,x\in\mathbb R \mid (x,y)\in D\}$ are all the possible $x$-values in the horizontal slice of $D$ where the second coordinate equals a fixed $y$. Hiding this behind $\iint_D$ is another bad idea.